# My first (simple) template that does more than storing a value of type T

Tags: c++, template

I just decided to get a bit more acustomed to using templates. Maybe this is a stupid question, but in my experience in C++ there is always some pitfall lurking aroung the corner. Thus I prefer the danger of embarresment instead of building up on bad habbits. Mainly as an exercise I wrote this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename V,template <class> class R = std::greater,typename I=void>
struct Extremum {
    typedef V    value_type;
    typedef I    index_type;
    typedef R<V> relation_type;
    V value;
    I index;
    R<V> r;
    bool operator() (V v,I i){
        bool result = r(v,value);
        if (result){
            value = v;
            index = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
    Extremum(V v,I i) : value(v),index(i) {}
    std::string toString(){
        std::stringstream s;
        s << "value= " << value << " index= " << index;
        return s.str();
    }
};

template <typename V,template <class> class R>
struct Extremum<V,R,void> {
    typedef V    value_type;
    typedef void index_type;
    typedef R<V> realtion_type;
    V value;
    R<V> r;
    bool operator() (V v){
        bool result = r(v,value);
        if (result){ value = v; }
        return result;
    }
    Extremum(V v) : value(v) {}
    std::string toString(){
        std::stringstream s;
        s << "value= " << value;
        return s.str();
    }
};
```

which would be used like this:

```
Extremum<int,std::greater,int > e(0,0);
e(10,3);
e(123,5);
std::cout << e.toString() << std::endl;

Extremum<int> g(0);
g(123);
g(1234);
g(1);
std::cout << g.toString() << std::endl;
```

I used a ´toString()´ because it is for debugging and printing to the screen while I might want to overload in/output operators for real in/output.

I dont like so much the ordering of the template parameters, as both the second and the third parameter would make a good fit as the last parameter so it can be ommited on the instantiation. However, I guess there is no better solution than simply choosing one ordering.

I have no idea how to provide good initial values. My idea was to use something like `std::numeric_limits<V>::max`, however, it depends too much on the choosen relation whether it should be `max`, `min` or something completely different. Maybe the easiest is  let the user choose them when calling the constructor.

Aside from its functionaliy, which probably could be achieved with less code and a simple lambda or the like, is there anything inherently broken with this code? Anything obvious that could be improved?

Note that this is pre-C++11, but I would also be interested in any post-C++11 stuff.

Comment: I haven't rolled back the edit, but please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)* for future reference. Thanks for keeping the answer cleanly in sync with the OP.

Comment: @Mat'sMug ok, sorry, my mistake. should have payed attention to warnings before posting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from cosmetic details, I see two things that could be improved IMHO.

#### The template comparator `R<V>`

As a template argument, you are asking for `template <class> class R`
which is then used so `R<V> r;`

This narrows the possibilities since you can't pass a non-template comparator.
For instance, if you have a custom type `MyType` and a custom comparator for that type `MyTypeComp` then you won't be able to use it with your `Extremum` struct because `MyTypeComp` doesn't accept template arguments.

The fix is easy:

```
template <
          typename V,
          class R,
          typename I = void
         >
struct Extremum {
    typedef V    value_type;
    typedef I    index_type;
    typedef R relation_type;
    V value;
    I index;
    R r;
    //...
```

And you would use it so:

```
Extremum<int, std::greater<int>, int> e(0,0);
Extremum<MyType, MyTypeComp, int> e(MyZero,0);
```

#### The index

You write almost the same code twice: once with index, once without.
You could avoid it by passing the index in a pair.
So you have only one `class Extremum<V, R>` and you set `V = std::pair<Value, Index>` and an appropriate comparator that compares two pairs according to their `Value` entry only.

```
template <class V, class R>
struct Extremum {
    typedef V    value_type;
    typedef R    relation_type;
    V value;
    R r;
    bool operator() (V v){
        bool result = r(v,value);
        if (result) {
            value = v; //you can use std::move here
        }
        return result;
    }
    Extremum(V v, R r) : value{v}, r{r} {} //you can use std::move here too
    std::string toString() const {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << "value= " << value;
        return s.str();
    }
};

template <class RV>
struct CompByFirstEntry {
    RV delegate;
    CompByFirstEntry(RV delegate);

    template <class V, class I>
    bool operator() (std::pair<V,I> const& lhs, std::pair<V,I> const& rhs) const {
        return delegate(lhs.first, rhs.first);
    }

    //or, even:

    template <class Pair>
    bool operator() (Pair const& lhs, Pair const& rhs) const {
        return delegate(lhs.first, rhs.first);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT :** Here is a working example.

- What changed: define the constructor `CompByFirstEntry::CompByFirstEntry` and `operator<<` for `std::pair`; choose one version of the `operator()`.
- Note: you can also create a class `ExtremumIndexed<V, I, R>` that extends `Extremum<std::pair<V,I>, MyPairComp<R>>` or simply a template using directive.

---

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::pair<int, int> const& p)
{
    out << p.first << " " << p.second;
    return out;
}

template <class V, class R>
struct Extremum {
    typedef V    value_type;
    typedef R    relation_type;
    V value;
    R r;
    bool operator() (V v){
        bool result = r(v,value);
        if (result) {
            value = v; //you can use std::move here
        }
        return result;
    }
    Extremum(V v, R r) : value{v}, r{r} {} //you can use std::move here too
    std::string toString() const {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << "value = " << value;
        return s.str();
    }
};

template <class RV>
struct CompByFirstEntry {
    RV delegate;
    CompByFirstEntry(RV delegate) : delegate{delegate} {}

    template <class V, class I>
    bool operator() (std::pair<V,I> const& lhs, std::pair<V,I> const& rhs) const {
        return delegate(lhs.first, rhs.first);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    using MyPairComp = CompByFirstEntry<std::greater<int>>;
    MyPairComp comp(std::greater<int>{});
    int value = 1;
    int index = 0;

    Extremum<std::pair<int,int>, MyPairComp> e({value, index}, comp);
    std::cout << e.toString() << std::endl;

    e({value + 1, index - 1});
    std::cout << e.toString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you give an example of using `CompByFirstEntry`? Would it be: `typdef std::pair<T,U> P; Extremum<P,CompByFirstEntry<P> >;` ?

Comment: I had a missing return statement. Shame on me. If fixed it also in your answer

Comment: @tobi303 I edited my answer